# Leaking Toilet Base

Tags: toilet, base

Toilet leaks around base and smells of pee. The wax ring has been replaced several times and we still have the leak and smell.

Comment: This question might help to locate the problem, it gives leaks from toilet/tank, and problems with floor/drain pipe.   https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/185376/why-is-my-toilet-leaking-around-the-base-even-after-a-seal-replacement?rq=1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could just be someone with poor aim.  Leaking toilet should more smells.

Comment: A wax ring, while pretty forgiving, can only do so much.  Is it possible that the toilet to flange distance or angle is such that you are not getting a proper seal?

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem. Occasional sewage smell.

In my case it turned to be the wax ring.

They come in different hight version.

Check your bottom flange to the top of the floor hight and get corresponding wax ring sticking over the floor level.

Changing mine to the higher version solved the problem.

Also make sure to seal the perimeter between the toilet and the floor.